# Set up an Ubuntu 15.04 based mini-pc as WiFi router

Tags: wireless, file-sharing, router, scp

I am wondering if there is a way to set up a Ubuntu mini-pc with a WiFi adapter as a WiFi router, so that I can use my laptop to scp some files from it wirelessly.

Comment: Please consider using a current version of Ubuntu (12.04 LTS, 14.04 LTS or 15.10), since 15.04 already reached its end of life and doesn't have support anymore. Nice question though, +1

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yeah, I am thinking of update to 14.04 LTS in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done with *hostapd*. The Ubuntu documentation might be of help for you:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessAccessPoint